How can I convert a MKV video file to MP4 when the container does not support the codec?
I am using ffmpeg to try to downsample an mp4 but it will only output an mkv file, not an mp4 file apparently. So, I have an mkv file output. I tried to convert it to mp4 using the following command but got the error shown:

$ ffmpeg -i output.mkv -c copy output.mp4 
[mp4 @ 0x556237e63480] Could not find tag for codec pcm_s16be in stream #1, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument  

How can I convert it to mp4 using ffmpeg? The codec information for the mkv file is as follows:

Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'output.mkv':
Metadata:
TIMECODE        : 21:21:16;29
MAJOR_BRAND     : XAVC
MINOR_VERSION   : 16785407
COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: XAVCmp42iso2
ENCODER         : Lavf59.27.100
Duration: 00:04:07.75, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4244 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709/bt709/iec61966-2-4, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn

Metadata:
HANDLER_NAME    : Video Media Handler
VENDOR_ID       : [0][0][0][0]
ENCODER         : Lavc59.37.100 libx264
DURATION        : 00:04:07.747000000
Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16be, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
HANDLER_NAME    : Sound Media Handler
VENDOR_ID       : [0][0][0][0]
DURATION        : 00:04:07.750000000


UPDATE:
Note that the original downsampling command (from 1080p to 720p) used to create the original file (which resulted in the uncopyable mkv file was as follows:
$ ffmpeg -i H403.mp4 -filter:v scale=1280:-1 -c:a copy output.mkv 

If anyone could suggest how this command could be modified to generate a 720p mp4 file directly I would appreciate it. (Note that the file size difference is enormous: the original 1080p file is 1577 Mb but the 720p file is 8.8 Mb, almost 200x smaller).

Convert the audio to something supported by a MP4 container

FYI, Handbrake has lots of presets that just work.

If the file was in MP4 originally ("downsample an mp4") then perhaps share the initial downsampling command you used so it can be improved to output to MP4 in the first place.
For you now to convert back the MKV to MP4 you'd need to re-encode the audio to a supported audio format, you can use AAC:
ffmpeg -i output.mkv -c:v copy -c:a aac output.mp4

In order to do the original downsampling right away correctly to MP4, you can add the same audio re-encoding to the initial command:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v scale=1280:-1 -c:a aac output.mp4


Thanks very much. This deserves a bounty. I have updated my question to show the original downsampling command I used so if there is a way to go directly to a 720p mp4 I would be glad to know it.

Use -c:a pcm_s16le instead.

The command "mpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v scale=1280:-1 -c:a pcm_s161e copy output.mp4" results in an "invalid argument" error.

And simply ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v scale=1280:-1 -c:a copy output.mp4 gives what?

The same error.

Are you sure? (how can it be an invalid "argument" if the same exact thing works for the output.mkv?) Anyhow, you should certainly be able to do the re-encoding of the audio as part of the downsampling, see my edited answer

pcm_s161e is a typo in your command.
